# How many of the "Top 10 favorite British words" are understood by Americans?

Tags: meaning, american-english, british-english

Merriam-Webster Dictionary online shows “[Top 10 Favorite British Words](http://www.merriam-webster.com/top-ten-lists/top-10-favorite-british-words/)”. I’m interested in knowing how many of the listed words are understood or accepted by Americans as English, whichever British English or English slang.

The words listed as the top 10 Favorite English are:

1. *prat* meaning “a stupid person”,
2. *twee* meaning “affectedly or excessively dainty, delicate, cute, or quaint”,
3. *knackered* meaning “exhausted”,
4. *jiggery-pokery* meaning “dishonest activity, or nonsense”,
5. *plonk* meaning “cheap wine”,
6. *chunter* meaning “mutter”,
7. *whinge* meaning “whine”,
8. *gormless* meaning “stupid”,
9. *boffin* meaning “scientific expert”,
10. *pukka* meaning “genuine, first class”.

Comment: The only ones I missed were *plat* and *plonk*. *Pukka* I understood from reading histories of India under (ant. *cutch*), and I didn't know it had worked its way into British slang.

Comment: @Robusto: PLL has now corrected "plat" to "prat", and corrected a couple of the meanings.

Comment: "Chunter" also means "vomit", and in my experience that is the more common meaning.

Comment: @colin - don't you mean 'chunder' ?

Comment: @Colin Fine: *Prat* I understand.

Comment: I may be opening myself up for ridicule, but I'll go on record that my American ear hasn't heard most of these. The exceptions are _twee_, which I understood to be a genre of music, and _knackered_, which I think is more commonly known among Americans.

Comment: And with wordlists like these is why I refuse to admit to speaking English. I speak American.

Comment: @Yoichi: these are not "Top 10 Favorite British Words" in general. These are the "top 10 favorite British words" of the **american** editors of the online Merriam-Webster **american** dictionary. They have been chosen more for exotism to american ears than for frequent usage among the British.

Comment: @Yoichi: twee would certainly be a nice equivalent of "kawaï" かわいい in some contexts.

Comment: ....I recognised "Boffin" as a particular family of hobbits, who came to Bilbo's birthday...

Comment: I've only used "plonk" in an online bulletin board/email list context, where it most decidedly doesn't mean any sort of wine, cheap or otherwise. (It's used as a sort of onomatopoeia for the sound effect of adding someone to your kill file, i.e. setting your reader program to ignore the user.)

Comment: @MArtha - plonk also means to put something down or sit down in BE. So "plonk yourself on the sofa" isn't as bad as it sounds!

Comment: So leaving aside technical baseball,geographical or political terms - what are the top 10 Americanisms that British speakers wouldn't understand?

Comment: Frankly, I wouldn't say many of these are "favourites" in Britain. Knackered, whinge, gormless, and prat are fairly normal words here; twee is normal enough, but frankly I see it more in American writing than British; plonk, boffin, and pukka are understood, but not every day; jiggery-pokery is so uncommon that I don't think I've seen it in writing since I was a child, and I don't know that I've heard anyone say it.

Comment: I dont think "chunter" and "pukka" are very common in use in BrEng - well perhaps in England itself but less so in rest of British Isles. Though Jamie Olivier, the chef, is trying hard to make "pukka"  more familiar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a reasonably intelligent American, I understand seven of these without the definitions (prat, twee, knackered, plonk, whinge, boffin, pukka). I would say that none of those sound remotely native to the American English speaker with the possible exception of *twee*, which is occasionally used (although generally with a negative connotation -- sickeningly cute or cloying).

Comment: I understand five without definitions. I have definitely heard *twee* used (with strongly negative connotations) by American speakers, and I think *plonk* might be, but almost certainly not any of the others.

Comment: @Ernest: checking the source, it turns out *plat* in the question was indeed a typo for *prat*; have edited to correct that.  So you can up your 6/10 to 7/10 :-)

Comment: @Ernest/PLL/Robust-san. Sorry confusing you. I misspelt plat for prat. To Japanese who can't distinguish R and L sound, this is always a headache when typing in.

Comment: I have corrected the definition of "twee" (from the given source) to include "affectedly or excessively"

Comment: I only know *prat*, does that make me one 7th of an intelligent American?

Comment: @snumpy: Nope, it makes you a true Patriot :)

Answer (score 19):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that **none** of these words will be *correctly* understood by *most* Americans.

I'm college educated, fairly well-read, and I've *never even heard* of 6 out of the 10 of these.

- *Prat* is the only one that I could have defined correctly.
- I always thought that *knackered* meant *drunk*, but that's probably my own mis-understanding of the context in which I heard it
- I think I've heard *jiggery-pokery* and *whinge* before, but couldn't have defined them for you
- Never heard the other 6.

Comment: Maybe I need to watch more British comedies :)

Comment: the video link below is funnier  :)  **I completely agree with your first sentence - you have the correct answer.**

Comment: +1. I got a pretty dang high score on my SAT verbal (back in the pliestoscene age when I took it), and the only reason I know *any* of these words is either from personal exposure to Brits, or from reading Harry Potter.

Answer (score 5):

Just to give more perspective...

As an AmE speaker:

- only one, *chunter*, have I never heard of before.
- *jiggery-pokery* sounds like it's from some '30s (american) gangster movie.
- *plonk* and *boffin* don't sound particularly British to me and are rare to my ears.
- all the rest sound decidedly British, and if their meaning wasn't immediate out of context, the definition hints are all 'oh right, that's what it meant'. I feel like I can remember the instance for each one of them when I heard/read something British and I was shocked at this bizarre new word.

So 1 of these I've never heard of, 3 of these pass as general English, and the rest as particular to British English (not at all American).

That said, I wouldn't expect most Americans to recognize any of these, except maybe *jiggery-pokery*.

Comment: You won't hear the kids in the street saying 'jiggery-pokery' here either tbh.

Comment: That's a different matter altogether. I find (to my non BrE ears) _prat_, _knackered_, and _whinge_ to sound everyday, and _twee_ and _gormless_ to be very much used just not everyday.

Comment: "Boffin" had its heyday in the 1930s, and was archetypally British at the time.  Nowadays it is used almost exclusively by tabloid newspapers to belittle intelligent thought.

Comment: @All answerers. I’m amazed to find commonality or interactivity between British English and Am English with this question. It seems most American users understand or accept 6 to 9 words of the top 10 Favorite British English list as English. If I’m shown 10 Top Favorite Chinese Words, I may be able to guess the meaning of 1 to 2 words at the best, even we use the same characters, and even I have studied Chinese language in Beijing long before. It would be the same with Top 10 Japanese words to Chinese, again, with whom we share the same characters.

Comment: @Yoichi: There's no comparison; the distance between Chinese and Japanese (spoken or written) is astronomically larger than the distance between British and American English. That said, I would expect few Americans to recognize any of the words in the above list. "Favorite" is a very unscientific choice.

Comment: @Mitch. Phonetically yes. There’s “astronomic difference” between Japanese and Chinese. But on writing, as we have borrowed Chinese characters, words and literatures ever since around 3 Century, and have exported thousands of modern Japanese words since late 19 Century, .we can communicate pretty well each other in writing without knowing the other’s language. But when it comes to new words, I find ‘communicability in writing’ comes down to zero.

Comment: @Yoichi, you are getting a really bad sample.  **All** the yanks on this list are basically **extremely intelligent, language-oriented, and well-educated**.  It's a false positive!

Comment: @Joe Blow - I blush.

Comment: @MTHead Heh! - be sure to watch the video below to see some "non-list members" in action!  :)

Answer (score 2):

In my half century plus as an American, the only one of those words I have ever heard in conversation is "boffin". My hobby is plastic airplane modeling and in that small, specialized community the word is sometimes used referring to an expert on certain types of airplanes, usually British airplanes, and most often the Supermarine Spitfire.

Answer (score 2):

I'll toss in my answer.

I did not recognize *twee* as primarily British, and use it myself. I know *plonk* from Rumpole and some other British fiction, see it as British, don't use it. I thought *whinge* was Aussie in origin, it's not (yet) common in the States, but it's a great almost-onomatopoetic word, so I use it often. I knew *boffin* from a biography of Churchill, who used it in reference to the top scientists working for British war effort, see it as British, don't use it. Vaguely aware of *gormless* and *knackered*, hadn't heard of the others. I assume *pukka* is an import from the Raj?!

Comment: Yes, 'pukka' is an Anglo-Indian word, which seems to have been given a new lease of life by the TV cook Jamie Oliver.

Answer (score 1):

I'm American and here's my take:

Twee, plonk and pukka are three I'm not familiar with.

The other's I've heard or used myself.

Answer (score 1):

American here.

I recognized everything except Twee, plonk, chunter and pukka. I'm not sure what that says about me as most people seemed to have heard 'twee' before. I actually use 'whinge' more than 'wine' now.  I had always heard gormless to mean someone who was hopelessly naive or gullible rather than stupid. I also took prat to be more like 'jerk' than 'idiot'. Don't know if that's regional or because most of my vocabulary comes from context clues.

Comment: What's the AmE equivalent for "plonk?" Do you just say "cheap wine," or is there a specific term for it?

Comment: "Plonk" was used quite a bit in the dark comedy hit movie "sideways" a few years ago. The characters were wine experts. Ordinary Americans might say swill, Thunderbird, Boone's Farm, or rotgut.

Answer (score 1):

I know all of these but *chunter.* But then, I watch a lot of British TV.

Americans have heard *twee* a lot in recent years, because some social commentators have picked it up as a handy description of certain trends in pop culture and entertainment (and have broadened its meaning in the process).

Answer (score 1):

As a Briton, I can verify that *boffin* is still in used in schools, where it has been abbreviated to *boff*.  It is used by schoolchildren to refer to a child who is particularly clever, and is therefore a target for abuse and ridicule. I have heard both my children referred to as *boff* by their peers.

I'm amazed no-one has mentioned the etymology of *plonk* in this thread though, so here goes.  British and Australian soldiers in World War One converted the French *vin blanc* into *plink-plonk* (amongst others, such as *ving blong*, *plinketty-plonk*), which became shortened to *plonk*, to refer to ordinary/cheap wine, though not necessarily bad wine. This died out in the UK, as the average man here didn't drink wine.  However, it survived in Australia, as they did make and drink wine there.  It returned to the UK in the 1950s, apparently.

A source of more info is [here](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-plo1.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Five out of ten for me. But I've heard 'pukka' used in a different sense. e.g., Two travelers (one American and one Brit) debark from ferry in Georgetown, Penang (Malaysia). While walking through streets, the Brit sees a Malaysian government employee in khaki uniform, which includes English baggie trousers. The Brit, noticing the baggy trousers, says: 'Penang is very pukka.' The American (me) interprets this remark to mean that among Penang's inhabitants, British customs,culture and clothing styles are still held in esteem despite Malaysia becoming an independent nation.