# How to affectionately call someone who is always moaning/whinging?

Tags: single-word-requests

How can one affectionately call someone who is always moaning/whinging? I am looking for a qualifier with minimal negative connotation.

Comment: I can think of a few that go with specific names - Moaning Lisa, for example...

Comment: Does a lot of whinging go on at a whing-ding?

Comment: "Don't be a debbie downer".

Comment: @mgkrebbs see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26935/how-many-of-top-10-favorite-british-words-are-understood-by-or-pass-as-english-a

Comment: Honestly, I think it has a lot more to do with how you say it than what exactly you're saying. Any of the answers given below, if said in anger, would have a much stronger negative connotation than if said gently or jokingly.

Comment: Do you mean "affectionate" as in "romantic" or merely "friendly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the Yiddish *[kvetch](http://www.wordnik.com/words/kvetch)* is sometimes used affectionately. And here's some other possibilities I can picture being said with appropriate warmth:

[bellyacher](http://www.wordnik.com/words/bellyacher)
[codger](http://www.wordnik.com/words/codger)
[crab](http://www.wordnik.com/words/crab)
[crankypants](http://www.wordnik.com/words/crankypants)
[croaker](http://www.wordnik.com/words/croaker)
[curmudgeon](http://www.wordnik.com/words/curmudgeon)
[sorehead](http://www.wordnik.com/words/sorehead)
[squawker](http://www.wordnik.com/words/squawker)

Answer (score 2):

I think the gentlest term I could think up of, was "bear":

> You have been a bear all morning! Let's be happy now.

How about "Moaner"? As in:

> Come, come, don't be a moaner!

There's also "whiner", or "groucho", or "grumpy" which is very gentle:

> Let's not be grumpy shall we?

Comment: One problem with _[bear](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bear)_ is its use in gay lingo to refer to husky, large men with a lot of body hair, but +1 for _[grumpy](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=grumpy+dwarf&hl=en&prmd=ivns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=TIT-TbH3EcyEtgfonNynAw&ved=0CBkQsAQ&biw=1280&bih=705)_.

Comment: @Callithumpian: lol I didn't know that :D

Answer (score 2):

Scots would use the term *stropper* or *stroppy*:

> My, you're being a wee bit stroppy this morning!

Answer (score 1):

My kids are always like that.  I called them "grumpy bum".  Combine a negative word with a cute or positive term.

Comment: smile. wondering which out of "grumpy" and "bum" is supposed to be the cute positive term, though!

Comment: well my 3 year old thinks bum is a very funny word =)