# Word for someone who rarely interacts and does so only to complain?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific term (noun) for a person who never otherwise interacts with their social media friends on their posts — save for once in a blue moon when they show up to comment with a criticism?

There's "cacoethes carpendi", but that's a description of the behavior and not the person, and even "carper" suggests the person's behavior is regular versus uncommon.  Same with "fusspot".  Something like "drive-by carper", though, is cumbersome.

Comment: I strongly suspect there is no word that also conveys the required meaning of *occasional*. That sense aside, this is a duplicate of [How to affectionately call someone who is always moaning/whinging?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30500/how-to-affectionately-call-someone-who-is-always-moaning-whinging). At best, you would have to qualify it with *occasional* or *drive-by*. I would vote to close this as a duplicate of that, but my single vote would be binding, and I'm not certain there is no word that doesn't also contain the "rare" aspect that's being asked for.